# javascript url regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

How can I allow users to enter both subdomain and domain names without the http:// prefix using a regex in javascript. I need to allow: `domainname.com or www.domainname.com or www.domainname.co.uk.` I have this at the moment which expects www. :

```
/^(?=www\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$/ix.test(value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(?=www\.)?[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$/
```

Marking the www group with a **?** makes it a zero-or-one match, which is what you want as I understand it.

Tested with http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: thanks for the simple answer - just ading the ? is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work when tested on http://www.regextester.com/

```
/^(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
```